# Assigning vector::iterator to char array post VS 2003

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2003, stl

I am trying to get some C++ code originally written in Microsoft Visual Studio (VS) 2003 to compile under VS 2008 and I am having trouble finding an efficient solution to assigning a vector::iterator to the beginning of a char array.  I know that iterators went from being a defined as a simple pointer type (T*) to a class type between VS 2003 and VS 2005.  Here is a simple example of what I am talking about:

```
typedef std::vector<char>       CharContainer;
typedef CharContainer::iterator InputIt;

int FindNumMsgs( InputIt _inputIter, int _len );

int ProcessBufferForMsgs( char buf[], const size_t maxlen )
{
    int numMsgs = FindNumMsgs( InputIt(buf), maxlen );
    ...
}
```

So, in VS 2003, this compiles and works with no problem (since iterators are defined as T*).  In VS 2008, this errors with C2440 (function-style-cast) since I can no longer just assign the iterator with the buf pointer.  What would I do to get this to work in VS 2008 now that iterators are a class type?  I could copy the buffer into a vector, then pass in myVec.begin(), but I have to think that I can avoid this overhead.

Comment: This is a perfect example of "technical debt". Someone used a quick hack to make things work, now you're left to pay off the mortgage. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution would be to template `FindNumMsgs` such that it can work with either iterators or pointers (since pointers can be used as iterators just fine). Something like this:

```
template <class T>
int FindNumMsgs(T it, int count) {
    while(count--) {
        // do whatever
        it++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: The standard library prefers to use begin,end as parameters rather than begin,count. I would follow their lead. You can always use begin+count in the function call.

Comment: true enough, but i wanted to offer a solution which is consistant with his existing code.

Comment: but, lets not forget about `fill_n` and similar ;-).

Comment: After looking at all the code that will be affected, I decided that this was the best solution.  Thanks Evan and props to Mark as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `FindNumMsgs` accepts `char*` as the first parameter, maybe you could just use a simple `char*` pointer:

```
int ProcessBufferForMsgs( char buf[], const size_t maxlen )
{
    char* simpleIterator = buf;
    int numMsgs = FindNumMsgs( simpleIterator, maxlen );
    ...
}
```

Comment: The first arg in FindNumMsgs is a vector<char>::iterator.

Answer (score 0):

What's the signature of FindNumMsgs? If it takes a char* you can just replace `InputIt(buf)` with `buf`. If it doesn't, there's little you can do about it without changing FindNumMsgs.

Comment: Well, FindNumMsgs takes a vector<char>::iterator as the first argument.  The whole point of this question is to avoid changing the function call, which does more than my simple example implies.

Comment: I only see two options: (1) Turn FindNumMsgs into a template (accepting arbitraty iterators) or overload it with a char* or const char* parameter. (2) Copy your buffer to a vector and use the vector's iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Time to refactor. You need to change FindNumMsgs to take a (const?) char * as input, or maybe provide a second overloaded version. Better yet make it a templatized function that takes a begin/end pair of anything with iterator or pointer semantics.

Comment: Well, there are a bunch of functions that would have to be refactored and quite frankly, templatization would be overkill here.  Again, I could just copy the buffer into a vector, pass in it's .begin() operator and be on my merry way, but I feel that there has to be a way to do this without having to do a copy.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like the commercial where the guy is on his lawn mower and says "I'm in debt up to my eyeballs!"  :-)  I am mainly just trying to figure out if one can still use iterators directly on an array, without actually copying it into a container.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of vector<T>::iterator. In any case you really shouldn't bother packaging a pointer into a vector<T>::iterator. And this "should" really means don't try it. If you're too lazy to change anything you still could try to compile your code in release mode.